# What happens to native code (JNI) when an android app is compiled?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Based on my understanding of Android, it seems that a Java code is first converted into .class files, which are then converted into the proprietary Dalvik byte code format. This can be reverse engineered back to Java source code.

My questions is, what happens to native code (written in C++), which is used in JNI ? Will someone be able to get the c++ source code ? Or will they just get byte code of the C++ ?

EDIT: I don't know what happens to native code, when an app is compiled for android. Can someone explain what happens when you use JNI ?

Comment: Neither. They'll get native machine code.

Comment: so c++ code in java is harder to disassemble than a pure java app ?

Comment: Dalvik leaves the C++ code alone why generating the byte code ?

Comment: There's no "C++ code". There's just a DSO binary that gets loaded into the process space by the dynamic loader. You can hand-write the DSO in assembler if you prefer, or compile it from Pascal or Rust. The JNI only specifies a loose ABI using C declarations as a de-facto ABI standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB - so the code written in c++, when compiled becomes native, but not dalvik byte code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNI calls are bound in runtime. The libraries are stored as is. Android is based on linux kernel so no problems to run library compiled for corresponding architecture

Comment: @John Yes, it is native code (that is why it is called JNI)